# Margin with a JPanel inside another JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, margin, layout-manager

I am using JPanel to simulate squares. The idea is to put a sort of filter in front of a JPanel.

The first JPanel contains an ImageIcon and a background color.
A second JPanel containing a background color with transparency is put inside the first one.

I did it, but i have a problem : a margin is appearing in the top where the second JPanel doesn't cover the first one.

EDIT : code
class JPanelImage extends JPanel

```
private ImageIcon imageIcon = null;
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{       
    if(imageIcon != null)
    {   
        Image image = imageIcon.getImage(); 

        int height = 30;
        int width = 18;

        int marginLeft = (this.getWidth()-width) / 2;
        int marginTop = (this.getHeight()-height) / 2;

        super.paintComponent(g);                        
        g.drawImage(image, marginLeft, marginTop, width, height, this);
    }
    else
        super.paintComponent(g);
}
public void addColoredLayout(Color color) {
    JPanelImage upperLayout = new JPanelImage();
    upperLayout.setOpaque(true);
    upperLayout.setBackground(color);
    upperLayout.setPreferredSize(this.getPreferredSize());

    this.add(upperLayout);

}
```

I also have a Window class (extending JFrame) that create a JPanel and apply the addColoredLayout method.

Comment: This could be a layout issue or border issue. Show us an example so we can determine which

Comment: I'm just learning Java right now, so i don't really know the concept of layouts. Therefore it's probably a border issue...

Answer (score 0):

We have a gridBagLayout on the mainJPanel (which is the frame contentPane) and we had JPanelImage (a JPanel with a image on it) to mainJPanel.When we try to add a JPanel to these JPanelImage, we have the problem he told you.

```
mainJPanel.setLayout(gridBagLayout);
gridBagLayout.preferredLayoutSize(this.getContentPane()); // this.getContentPane() = mainJPanel 
(...)
GridBagConstraints gridBagConstraints;
(...)
gridBagConstraints.gridy = i;
gridBagConstraints.gridx = j;
(...)
gridBagConstraints.insets = new Insets(0, 0, marginBot, marginRight);
gridBagConstraints.ipadx = 0;
gridBagConstraints.ipady = 0;
(...)    
mainJPanel.add(tmpJPanelImage, gridBagConstraints);
```

EDIT : I just found the solution :

```
((FlowLayout) this.getLayout()).setVgap(0);
```

Thank you MadProgrammer for the hint.